# What's the difference between `pipenv install --index` and `pipenv install --pypi-mirror`?

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

`pipenv install` command reference [here](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#pipenv-install).

> -i, --index 
>   Target PyPI-compatible package index url.
>
> --pypi-mirror 
>   Specify a PyPI mirror.

Besides, environment variable `PIP_INDEX_URL` corresponds to `--index`, `PIPENV_PYPI_MIRROR` corresponds to `--pypi-mirror`,

If I get a pypi mirror url, what's the difference between passing it as `--index=<url>` and as `--pypi-mirror=<url>`? It seems that both methods work for me.

Comment: with `--index`, you could install from your own private pypi repo, like a devpi server.

Comment: I haven't used any private index yet. Maybe that's what made me confused about theses two params. In my case, I only use PyPI mirrors. Passing the mirror url to `--pypi-mirror` and `--index` both work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is an interesting question, the doc of pipenv is unclear on the difference of those two options, then the best source is [its source code](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/v2018.11.26/pipenv/core.py#L1322-L1362), as of version v2018.11.26, its behavior roughly like:

- you could specify multiple `--index`, they formed the *source list* of packages, they could be the PyPI url or a private repository url.
- only one `--pypi-mirror` could be specified.
- if `--pypi-mirror` is used, for each PyPI source url in the source list, would be replaced with mirror url.
- in the end, pipenv shell out all sources to `pip install`, with `--index-url`, and `--extra-index-url` option if there is more than one source.

if you only install from PyPI, the net effect of both methods is the same.

Answer (score 0):

in my case with pipenv v2021.5.29 running from CLI, to replace `pip --undex-url` having private PyPI address and creds in the url, I should use `pipenv --pypi-mirror`, otherwise `pipenv --index` will fail to find the package.